# What button should be pressed after entering arguments with sys.stdin.read() in python

Tags: python, stdin

Iam working in a simple python code that uses sys library to get a multi-lines input through cmd, I am using sys.stdin.read() to enter my input like that:

```
3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30
```

then i don't know what to press to run the program.

i tried pressing enter, Ctrl+D and Ctrl+z Nothing happened

```
#Uses python3
import sys

def max_dot_product(a, b):
    a = sorted(a)
    b = sorted(b)
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        res += a[i] * b[i]
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    data = list(input.split())
    n = data[0]
    a = data[1:(n + 1)]
    b = data[(n + 1):]
    print(max_dot_product(a, b))
```

Comment: If you're actively using `read`, that means that you've already started your program.  Did you enter `python <file name>`?  It sounds as if you need to review your introductory notes for the Python system you're using.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .. I have already run my python file then the file required the input, so I wrote it in the cmd but i don't know what button to press in the cmd to pass my input .. that's what i meant @Prune

Answer (score 1):

The input works fine for me; I used `enter` (optional) and `ctrl-D` after the last pair of values.

From there, the program fails because you try to multiply strings.  You have to convert the input to numeric.

```
data = list(map(int, input.split()))
```

Output:

```
3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30
[3, 50, 60, 20, 100, 50, 120, 30]
9100
```